# How to group from multiple queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL script that contain two tables, all of them have two columns ID and value,
and I am joining them using union, but the issue is if two table have the same id the id will be duplicated but I want the id to be shown one time and sum the value so instead of this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |

I want this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 7 |

here is my script:

```
select v.id,  v.value 
from (
SELECT  h.slxact# as id, (sum(nvl(d.DSCNT_AMT,0))  +     sum(nvl(d.PYMT_AMT,0))) as value  
FROM  pymnt d, invoice h
WHERE  d.slxact# = h.slxact#
and d.branch_cd = h.branch_cd
group by h.slxact#

UNION 

SELECT  h.slxact# as id,   sum(nvl(d.PYMT_AMT,0))  as value   
FROM   retn d, invoice h
WHERE  d.slxact# = h.slxact#
and d.branch_cd = h.branch_cd
group by h.slxact#
) as v

group by v.id
```

so my question is how I sum the value of similar ids, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select 
v.id
,sum(v.value)

from ( select id, 
       value1 as value
       from table_1
       union
       select id, 
       value2 as value
       from table_2
) v
group by v.id;
```

Comment: thanks but what if the column value has different name in the second table ?

Comment: give the same alias 
`value1 as value`
P.S. I have edit the answer

Comment: I got an error  00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Do you try to update something? 
write the full statement that raise the error. 
Also what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I add my full script in the question and the I am using oracle sql developer

Comment: add a semicolon at the end of `group by v.id;`

Comment: I added but still the same issue

Comment: ok it worked I had to delete as from union tables at the end